# objective c using NSString in switch cases

Tags: objective-c, string, switch-statement, case

i want to pass string as switch case parameter. How to do it ??

i have tried enum like

```
typedef enum _KeyPath
{
     KeyPathNone,
     KeyPathRefreshCount,
     KeyPathTimesLaunched,
     KeyPathCount
} KeyPath;
```

but i cant understand how to pass this enum values to switch case.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The switch/case statement of C/Objective-C *cannot* be used with strings, only with integer values.

Comment: I know that but I want to ask that is there is any way like using enum or any thing coz in my application i need to check for many cases of string and for that Im using number of if else statements. and i want to get rid of it.

Comment: @pallavi Please paste the actual code and perhaps we will be able to help. Replacing `if-else` by a `switch` doesn't actually change code structure, it will be a purely cosmetic change. If you want to get rid of many if-else statements, you will have to add more info. Also consider using codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Name of enum> <enum object> = "String value you want to pass"
```

Example:

```
enum Test{
A,
B
}


Test city = A;

switch (city) {
    case B:
        //print B
    break;

   case A:
       //print A
       break;   
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
typedef enum _KeyPath
{
    KeyPathNone = 0,
    KeyPathRefreshCount,
    KeyPathTimesLaunched,
    KeyPathCount
} KeyPath;
```

Now KeyPathNone is 0, KeyPathRefreshCount is 1, KeyPathTimesLaunched is 2, …

So you can pass the actual names as parameters to a switch statement.